# how to append data to a model for a treeview in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have 2 qml tableviews. when i click on the 1st one i get an id from the selected row and then i filter the 2nd table based on that id.
In qml i am doing like this(pseudocode):

```
TableView {
    .....
    onclick: {
       var id = table1model.getid(currentIndex)
       table2.model.clear
       for(index in sourceModel) {
           if (condition()) {
               table2.model.append(index)
            }//end if
        }//end for
    }//end onclick
}//end table1

TableView {
    id: table2
    ....
}
```

The problem is nothing gets displayed in table2 even if some items are added to the model. Can i append to a model an index from another model(they have the same structure, practically the table2 model is a subset of the sourceModel which is registered in context)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. To help us helping you it is important to provide a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when ever possible. So please read the linked document, and provide us with the code you tried (as real QML, not pseudocode) in a form that complies with the requirements of a mcve. I saw, you went to great lenghts to get the code formatted, but it is easier to use the reccomended way (that even formats it more beautiful). See either my edit, or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format it right.

Comment: Thank you. I will update with the real example but at the moment my work is not on this computer. Basically my primary question was if it is possible to append to a model indexes from another model.

Comment: I would suggest to either use a filter proxy model for the second view which filters on the criteria provided by the first model, or have two models working on the same data where one is only showing the subset. In both cases your QML code does not need to deal with any data handling, just pass the filter criteria on to the second model

Answer (score 0):

You should append model item, not only index. Index is just a number.

```
var obj = table1.model.get(index);
table2.model.append(obj);
```

provided that both tables use the same structure.

But to get detailed answer you have to provide mcve, as @derM already noticed.

Comment: Thank you. I will update my post with the specific details.

Comment: But I see that QAbstractModelItem has no method get(index).I should implement a get method and make it Q_INVOKABLE?

Comment: [ListModel.get()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)

Comment: index in my case is a QModelIndex, not an integer.

Comment: Ok, you didn't provide information about your models. Also you have to decide what view do you use - TreeView (as in question title) or TableView (as in code). I advice you create new question according with mcve, as @derM noticed if you really want to get answer.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. it is a tableview not treeview. so both controls are tableviews.